# How to append returned value(on sucess(data)) of ajax to different file

Tags: ajax

Am doing a simple ajax call as follow...
The following code is in index.html.

```
$("#tmTrendinSignIn").click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
 jQuery.post("http://code.xxx.com/workspace/xyz/xxx/login/authenticateuser",{
            'sleUsername': $("#sleUsername").val(),
            'slePassword' : $("#slePassword").val(),
        },function(strData,strTextStatus,objXMLHttpRequest){ 
            if (strData != 'Invalid username or password!!'){ 
                window.location.replace("dashboard.html");
                $("#dashboardmenu").append(strData);
            }else 
            {
                $('#loginTmTerror').append("<span class='label-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o text-danger'></i> </span><label class='control-label'>"+strData+"</label>");
                return false;
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Here am getting strData(Properly), now i need to append this strData to another file called 'dashboard.html'.

Comment: What do you mean by `appending data to another file`? Do you mean adding this into the static content of that HTML file or just add to the another iframe which renders that HTML file?

Comment: no no, please check the code, the code which was written in the above is in index.html and on success am getting strData that strData i need to append to dashboard.html(in this file i need to append to particular div)